# Assembly TSR(Terminate-Stay-Resident) on interupt 9h

Tags: assembly, dos, tsr

I created program that changes basic INT 9h in assembly with my own routine called "tastatura".

```
_inst_09:

cli
xor     ax, ax
mov     es, ax
mov     bx, [es:09h*4]
mov     [stari_int09_off], bx 
mov     bx, [es:09h*4+2]
mov     [stari_int09_seg], bx

mov     dx, tastatura
mov     [es:09h*4], dx
mov     ax, cs
mov     [es:09h*4+2], ax
sti
ret
```

The thing i want to do is to make this program resident. What i mean is that when my program is finished i still want INT 9h to point at my routine.
I know that i need to use `mov ah,31h` and  `int 21h` to create TSR but i dont know where to put it.
 It would be good if u give me an actual answer rather than some links and tutorials because i read them all, and read all books and i still could not figure it out.
 If you need whole code i can edit post and put it on.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `sti`, you invoke function 31h of the interrupt 21h:

```
mov ax, 3100h ; function 31h in AH, exit code 0 in AL
mov dx, 17 ; memory size to keep; 16 for PSP alone
int 21h
```

That's it. Your program terminates but stays in memory. The line after `int 21h` will not execute.

Comment: Doesn't DOS use the value of `dx` (number of paragraphs to keep resident) when you TSR  to update the amount of free conventional memory?

Comment: I have a little problem. When my program terminates i cannot type anything. Its like the screen is frozen

Comment: That's an unrelated problem; please accept this one and ask a new question. Most likely, your int 9 interrupt handler is wrong. Are you invoking the original handler first thing?